# Using hypersleep to offset time dilation?

Tags: society, relativity, slower-than-light

Say you need to go on a business trip where you'll be traveling .5c for one year to get to where you're going, do what you need to do for a few weeks then head back - you'd come back to find everyone you cared about would have aged substantially more than you.

Would it be plausible to have a society where it is standard to ask your spouse and children (and cat) to go into hypersleep for the exact amount of time needed to make it so they would have aged just the same few weeks (or less) as you (you will be in hypersleep for the transit time of your journey), and then everyone emerges from hypersleep when you get home, so you have all aged about the same when you get home?

Comment: So all the other people who know your wife and kids (relatives, friends) have to live without them just so the selfish twat who had a *business trip* could freeze *his* life.  Well that can't possibly screw up anyone's life, can it ?

Comment: Sounds rather story based.  In the sense that, sure, it's plausible.  Just write it.  Though i agree with @StephenG 's take too.

Comment: I have a better idea. Smoke, drink, sleep little and overeat during the trip so that you age as much as those who stay.

Comment: In some Greg Egan novel or other (Diaspora, maybe?) there is an insular civilization which slows itself down whenever one of its members travels off-world so that they will experience the same subjective time.  (The effect is even more pronounced since the traveller is not transmitted in a conscious state.)  The traveler makes it clear that she considers this a sort of blackmail, forcing her to be about her business and return quickly so everyone can get on with their lives.

Comment: "Substantially more" = 15% more -- they aged 2 years 4 months while the business traveller aged 2 years. And what @StephenG said.

Comment: @Cyn says it "sounds rather story based". 55 years ago, Rod Serling wrote what is effectively the canonical story for this theme. If you can find it, watch the episode. If not, Wikipedia provides a summary of [The Long Morrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Long_Morrow), including the ending spoiler.

Answer (score 6):

No, it wouldn't make sense, because one's social network is larger than just spouse, children and cat/dog.

What about your work colleagues? What about your favorite butcher? What about your friends at the bar down the street? And, once they also go hypersleep, what about their social network?

As you see, once you start, you quickly end up in sending all world to sleep just because you have to travel.

Comment: *Your favorite butcher* ?  We have very different social priorities. :-)

Comment: So when I go to a specific butcher, it's for the quality of the meat, not the quality of the cut. Wouldn't it make more sense to put the cows / sheep into hypersleep, not the butcher?

Comment: @TimBII, maybe my butcher was really skilled and knew which cut I liked.. maybe it is like you say, and then for a single traveler we have to put to sleep an entire planet

Comment: how you cut meat does matter.  There is thickness, how you cut it vs the grain, how much you prune the fat, etc.

Comment: Also, aging and preservation methods vary.

Comment: Ha ha well it's not so much about the butcher but about having things set up in your life they way you like them.  If I'm in a new place, it can take months or more to get back into my rhythm of where I shop to find what foods and other things.  And I'd have to move too, cause who can keep a house dorment for years (or at least if I leased the place, I'd have to pull my stuff from storage).  New hairdresser.  New chiropractor.  New doctor.  New gym.  New dance teacher.  What a PITA.

Answer (score 2):

**No**

if you were to travel that far that your family would die or at least age greatly, they would travel with you.

If you watch the movie [Passengers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passengers_(2016_film)), it's usually a one way journey but for Aurora, she plans on returning to Earth but she accepts everyone she knows will have died by the time she gets back.

There would be no point having your family wait for you frozen as everybody they know will also be dead besides what about your home and possessions? I'd expect you'd sell them and invest the money for your return or take the money with you if it's one way. Your home wouldn't be very good after being empty all that time.